# Template argument that takes templates as well (nested templates)

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I am trying to avoid code duplication, for the following thing:

```
template<class StringType, typename type1, typename type2, class MapType>
void readDatastructure(MapType<type1, type2> map, const StringType path) {
... some code
}
```

I have several different map types that have different `type1` and `type2` parameters. At some point I want to statically check what types are `type1` and `type2` and I can't figure out how to get this thing to compile. I have tried couple of variations on that template declaration and none of them seem to work. Is that even possible?

Cheers,

Comment: *At some point I want to statically check what types are `type1` and `type2`* Please elaborate that.

Comment: I meant I want to use `std::is_type` to determine the control flow of my code, later on in the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something along the lines of

```
template<class StringType, typename type1, typename type2,
         template<class, class> class MapType>
void readDatastructure(MapType<type1, type2> map, const StringType path);
```

But this won't work for, say, `std::map`, which has two extra template parameters (for the comparator and the allocator). So you either have to do

```
template<class StringType, typename type1, typename type2,
         template<class...> class MapType>
void readDatastructure(MapType<type1, type2> map, const StringType path);
```

or add extra template parameters, i.e.,

```
template<class StringType, typename type1, typename type2, class C, class A,
         template<class, class, class, class> class MapType>
void readDatastructure(MapType<type1, type2, C, A> map, const StringType path);
```

The first still doesn't work with a `std::map` taking non-default comparator/allocators; the second doesn't work if your map doesn't have exactly four template type parameters - e.g. `unordered_map`, which has five.

Thus, it's probably better to have your map type publish those types. `std::map`, for instance, publishes them as `key_type` and `mapped_type`. By "publish", I mean defining them as member typedefs. Then you can write

```
template<class StringType, class MapType>
void readDatastructure(MapType map, const StringType path);
```

and use e.g., `typename MapType::key_type` in place of `type1`.

If you can't change your map types, and they don't follow the standard protocol, you can write a traits class and specialize it for your map types:

```
template<class T>
struct map_traits {
    using key_type = typename T::key_type;
    using mapped_type = typename T::mapped_type;
};
template<class T1, class T2>
struct map_traits<MyBrokenMap<T1, T2>> {
    using key_type = T1;
    using mapped_type = T2;
};
```

Then you can use `typename map_traits<MapType>::key_type` etc.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the publish things?

Comment: Thank you, this is a very comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 1):

template template parameters

```
template<class StringType, typename type1, typename type2, template <typename, typename > class MapType>
```

Answer (score 1):

All std:: map types define the types `key_type` and `mapped_type`.

It's straightforward to write an is_map trait to constrain template function expansion.

example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>


template<class Map> struct is_map
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<class K, class V, class Comp, class Alloc>
struct is_map<std::map<K, V, Comp, Alloc>>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template<class K, class V, class Comp, class Hash, class Alloc>
struct is_map<std::unordered_map<K, V, Comp, Hash, Alloc>>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template<
class Map,
class String,
std::enable_if_t<is_map<Map>::value>* = nullptr
>
void readDataStructure(Map& map, String&& path)
{
    std::cout << "reading map with key type: " << typeid(typename Map::key_type).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "      and with value type: " << typeid(typename Map::mapped_type).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--------------------------"  << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> m1;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::wstring> m2;
    readDataStructure(m1, "foo.txt");
    readDataStructure(m2, "foo.txt");
}
```

example output:

```
reading map with key type: i
      and with value type: NSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE
--------------------------
reading map with key type: i
      and with value type: NSt3__112basic_stringIwNS_11char_traitsIwEENS_9allocatorIwEEEE
--------------------------
```